# 2002 lincoln LS 3.9 v8. coolant temperature sensor location, does anyone knows where is it at?

Tags: sensor, temperature, lincoln

the computer is saying that the temperature sensor is bad. i want to replace it, but i can't find where is it at.  engine light is on.

I have look for it all over google, the auto parts store, and so far no one knows where it could be at.  if anyone knows, please share.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Per [another article](https://www.justanswer.com/ford/16ekb-location-engine-coolant-tempature-sensor.html) I found it calls it the “cylinder head sensor” though it monitors coolant temp.

If this is correct, it right on the top of the motor. Now this article is for a 2001, however from searching, the same motor configuration was used for 2000-2002, so it should match up.

Comment: Go figure ... looks like it's under the intake manifold. IIRC, this is basically a Jaguar engine. Great fun. English engineering at it's best ;-) J/K! (BTW, I'm a fan of the LS ... great cars when they came out!).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 yeah. Google says Jag AJ Motor... spins right?

Comment: Diagram in the article looks correct. Have fun pulling the intake, OP... It's pretty similar to doing a 4.6 intake something like 3 hrs.